# Linux: iframe being injected into php file, but modify timestamp not being modified

Tags: linux

I have a php site with a file that is getting an iframe regularly injected into it.  Permissions on the file are 544 and on the directory are 555.

The file is clearly having the iframe injected, yet when I run stat  the modify date is still old (i.e. long before the hack occured).

How can a file have its contents modified without the modify flag being updated?

Comment: Are there ads or user content served on the site?

Comment: if you're using free hosting the provider can do that on page download. If the timestamp isn't updated most likely the file hasn't been changed and the iframe is comming from somewhere else. (extra js files loaded?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was a hack, likely the attacker simply reset the modification time of the file back to its original modification time.

If you want to make sure a file has its original integrity, use a signature function (e.g. sha1, md5) to create a checksum of the file to reference or use a SCM tool such as git or svn to keep track of the changes to your files.

Answer (score 0):

Modification dates can be set to the past using the [touch](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/touch/) command like this:

```
touch -t <timestamp> filename
```

My guess is you got someone funny on your system. Consider "[hardening](https://www.google.at/search?q=linux%20hardening)" your system, especially making sure everything is logged (and the logs protected, best at a remote server only you have access to).